# K-moment for exponential distribution

Tags: distribution, exponential

I'm trying to find k-moment for exponential distribution using characteristic function but when I calculate first, second, third moment I dont see any dependencies.

Comment: You have much confidence in us to ask such a question here! Actually, though my own stochastics are too rusty to answer, someone might know. But someone else *might* close your question as off-topic, first. We'll see. If you get no answer here, then you might (or might not) find better luck on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is quick sketch. For [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) is

CF(t) = 1/(1 - i t/L)

Moments could be computed as derivatives

E[X<sup>N</sup>] = i<sup>-n</sup> d<sup>n</sup>/dt<sup>n</sup> CF(t)|<sub>t=0</sub>

Obviously, derivative would make power at the denominator by 1, and move lambda

d<sup>n</sup>/dt<sup>n</sup> CF(t) = (i/L)<sup>n</sup> /(1 - i t/L)<sup>n+1</sup>

So put it into moments expression, i<sup>n</sup> cancels i<sup>-n</sup>, when t=0 denominator is equal to 1. and what is left

E[X<sup>N</sup>] = L<sup>-n</sup>

You could compare with wiki article on exponential distribution where mean is equal to L<sup>-1</sup> and variance is L<sup>-2</sup>.